How to select an input element with id in react jest?
Hi i am new to react and testing using jest. i want to select an input element with its id attribute.
below is the html
<input id="input-id" name="protocol" type="radio" value="somevalue">

how can i select this input.
i have tried below,
userEvent.click(screen.getByRole('input').hasAttribute('id', 'input-id'));

but this doesnt work. could someone help me with this.thanks.

Can you try https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/bytestid ?

i dint want to add data-test-id

getByRole('input', { value: { text: 'somevalue' } }) or maybe getByRole(input, { name: 'protocol' }) ?

testing-library doesn't let you select an element by it's id. It looks like the input item you posted has a type of 'radio'. You might try changing your code as shown below:


const inputElement = screen.getByRole('radio');

userEvent.click(inputElement);



This won't work if you have more than one radio element in your render.
Can you share the entire rendered html?
You should be able to get that by putting a screen.debug() in place of your userEvent.click call.
